# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'rank'

Tags: python, api, discord.py

i'am trying to make an Hypixel API command, but i get an error if the person doesn't have an rank.
My code:

```py
import requests

@commands.command() 
    async def api(self, ctx):
        user = ctx.message.content[5:]
        key = "#############"
        r2 = requests.get(f"https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/{user}")
        uuid = r2.json()
        r = requests.get(f"https://api.hypixel.net/player?key={key}&uuid={uuid['id']}")
        d = r.json()

        e = discord.Embed(color=0xff7373)
        e.set_author(name=f"{uuid['name']}'s Hypixel Stats:")
        e.set_thumbnail(url=f"https://mc-heads.net/avatar/{uuid['id']}.png")
        e.add_field(name="Rank:", value=d['player']['rank'].capitalize())
        e.add_field(name="Bedwars Wins:", value=d['player']['achievements']['bedwars_wins'])
        e.set_footer(text=f"UUID: {uuid['id']}")

        await ctx.send(embed=e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just catch the exception:

```
try:
    e.add_field(name="Rank:", value=d['player']['rank'].capitalize())
except KeyError:
    pass
```

This will add the rank field only if the player has an actual rank.